# Bootstrap Modal Form wont work with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very new to codeigniter.

here's my problem. when i load my MODAL LOGIN form and i press the submit button. It wouldn't do anything. What i would like to happen is just to go to these 4 views (student,instructor,adviser,admin) pages. I don't want to pass values for now. Focus only on switching views.

index.php (the modal part)

```
<!-- Modal Log in Form-->

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
               <form action="" method="POST" id="form" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter id no.">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
                </div>
                  <input type="Submit" value="LOG IN" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
              <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
              <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

I didn't put anything on that action="". because of this.(to be dynamic) when the user want to sign in as student he/she go to student page. or as admin he/she go to admin page. and etc.

freelancer.js

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myBtn").click(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("form").action ="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/logbooks/studentsignin'?>";
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myBtn2").click(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("form").action ="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/logbooks/instructorsignin'?>";
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("form").action ="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/logbooks/advisersignin'?>";
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myBtn4").click(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("form").action ="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/logbooks/adminsignin'?>";
            });
        });
```

logbooks.php (from the controller)

```
  class logbooks extends CI_Controller{

  function __construct(){
              parent::__construct();
  }

  function studentsignin(){
              $this->load->view('student_view');
  }

 function instructorsignin(){
              $this->load->view('instructor_view');
  }

  function advisersignin(){
              $this->load->view('adviser_view');
  }

  function adminsignin(){
              $this->load->view('admin_view');
  }
```

}

but if i just input the relative path for example http://localhost/WEB/index.php/logbooks/studentsignin in the browser. I can view the student page.

PLEASE help. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit button to just button.

In click event after set **"form action"** you can use this too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myBtn4").click(function(){
      $("#myModal").modal();
      $("#form").attr('action',"<?php echo base_url('index.php/logbooks/adminsignin')?> ";
      });
   $("#form").submit();
});
```

The point is use `$("#form").submit();`

I hope It Work For you.